# Download spark-submit without all the Spark framework to make lite Docker image

Tags: docker, apache-spark

Most of the Docker image that embed Apache Spark have the whole spark archive in it.

Also most of the time, we submit the spark application on kubernetes, hence the spark job is running on other Docker container.

As such, I am wondering, in order to make the Docker image smaller, **how to embed spark-submit feature?**

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question! I had a look (for the latest one on the [Downloads page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html): 3.3.1) and found the following:

Looking at the contents of `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit`, you can see the following line:

```
exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit "$@"
```

Ok, so it looks like the `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit` script calls the `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-class` script. Let's have a look at that one.

Similar to `spark-submit`, `spark-class` calls the `load-spark-env.sh` script like so:

```
. "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/load-spark-env.sh
```

This `load-spark-env.sh` script calls other scripts of its own as well. But there is also a bit about Spark jars in `spark-class`:

```
# Find Spark jars.
if [ -d "${SPARK_HOME}/jars" ]; then
  SPARK_JARS_DIR="${SPARK_HOME}/jars"
else
  SPARK_JARS_DIR="${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-$SPARK_SCALA_VERSION/jars"
fi

if [ ! -d "$SPARK_JARS_DIR" ] && [ -z "$SPARK_TESTING$SPARK_SQL_TESTING" ]; then
  echo "Failed to find Spark jars directory ($SPARK_JARS_DIR)." 1>&2
  echo "You need to build Spark with the target \"package\" before running this program." 1>&2
  exit 1
else
  LAUNCH_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_JARS_DIR/*"
fi

# Add the launcher build dir to the classpath if requested.
if [ -n "$SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES" ]; then
  LAUNCH_CLASSPATH="${SPARK_HOME}/launcher/target/scala-$SPARK_SCALA_VERSION/classes:$LAUNCH_CLASSPATH"
fi
```

So as you can see, it is referencing the spark jars directory (288MB of the total 324MB for Spark 3.3.1) and putting that on the launch classpath. Now, it's very possible that not all of those jars are needed in the case of submitting an application on kubernetes. But at least you need some kind of library to translate a spark application to some kubernetes configuration that your Kubernetes API server can understand.

So my conclusion from this bit is:

- We can quite easily follow which files are exactly needed. In first instance, I would say anything in `$SPARK_HOME/bin` and  `$SPARK_HOME/conf`. But that is no issue since they are all very small scripts/conf files.
- Some of those scripts though, are putting the jars directory in your classpath for the final java command.

  - Maybe they don't need all the jars, but they will need some kind of library to connect to the Kubernetes API server. So I would expect some jar to be needed there. I see there is a jar called `kubernetes-model-core-5.12.2.jar`. Maybe this one?
- Since most of the size of this `$SPARK_HOME` folder comes from those jars, you can try to delete some jars and run your `spark-submit` jobs to see what happens. I would think that, amongst others, jars like `commons-math3-3.6.1.jar` or `spark-mllib_2.12-3.3.1.jar` would not be necessary for a simple spark-submit to a Kubernetes API Server.

(All those specific jars just come from that one Spark version I talked about in the start of this post)

Really interesting question, I hope this helps you a bit! Just try deleting some jars, run your `spark-submit` and see what happens!

Comment: yes this is what I am looking for! building a spark version only to submit applications

Comment: I'll be following this question to see whether you manage to find anything interesting :)